# If a random process $\{Y_t\}_{t\ge0}$ whose moment of first order is uniformly bounded, does $Y_t/t$ converges to $0$ a.s.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have problem in reading the paper in the proof Theorem 3.6 (in Page 14):

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.386.7227&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I am puzzled here: it says $X(t)/t$ converges a.s. to $v$, and $X(t)-R(t)$ is tight, then concluding that $R(t)/t$ converges a.s. to $v$.

I think the author want to say that he concluded $(X(t)-R(t))/t \rightarrow 0$ a.s. by the tightness, but I failed.

- There is one counterexample for uniformly bounded first order moment process $Y_n$ whose time is discrete and $Y_n/n$ doesn't converges to $0$ a.s.: $Y_n$ are mutually independent, and $P(Y_n=n)=1/n, P(Y_n=0)=1-1/n$.

  Therefore, I think I need some property of the trajectory to have it, but the proof of the paper is really not clear to me.
- However, it is easy to see uniformly finite first moment obtains the convergence to $0$ in $L^1$.

It might cost you some time to read the paper, and it is very grateful for your help!

Comment: May be relevant: the measure for which $R(t)/t$ tends to $0$ a.s. is not the same as the measure for which $X(t)/t$ tends to $0$ a.s.

Comment: @motier It is true that they are not in the same measure originally, but the Propostion 2.3 which says the tightness couples those two processes together. Therefore I think we can just consider the new joint measure.

Comment: Like a stone sinking in seas... QAQ